# JS Error with JSON Response Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a page that generates a dropdown of options based on a prior selection. Once the parent dropdown is selected, that triggers a AJAX call which returns a JSON response of the child options.

```
function fetchLines(line) {

// Define vars we will use in this function
var dropdown = '';

// AJAX call to lines/sublines
$.ajax({
    url: baseURL + "index.php/Project/fetchLines",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        lineType: line
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    },
    success: function(data) {

        dropdown += '<option></option>';

        $(data.lines).each(function() {
            dropdown += '<optgroup label="' + this.line + '">';
            if (this.sublines.options) {
                $(this.sublines.options).each(function() {
                    dropdown += '<option value="' + this.subLine + '">' + this.subLine + '</option>';
                });
            }

            dropdown += '</optgroup>';
        });

        $('[name=line]').empty().append(dropdown).select2("enable", true).trigger('change');

    }

});
```

}

The issue I am running into is that there are some times no `sublines` in the JSON response which is causing the function to error out and not show results at all.

`TypeError: this.sublines is undefined`

JSON Response:

```
 [
 {
  "line":"Business",
  "sublines":{
     "options":[
        {
           "subLine":"Accounts"
        }
     ]
  }
},
{
  "line":"Consumer",
  "sublines":{
     "options":[
        {
           "subLine":"Cause"
        },
        {
           "subLine":"Financial Services"
        }
     ]
  }
 },
 {
  "line":"Risk"
 }
]
```

Is there a way I can prevent a missing node `subLines` from breaking the function?

Comment: Where does `sublines` come from? And what do you think `this` is in that context?

Comment: Sublines is in the response. Line is the OptGroup Label and the Options are the Sublines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, don't take it wrong, but it looks like you have no idea what you're doing. Just trying to use variables like they would be magically there.

I **think** this is what you're trying to do:

```
var dropdown = '<option></option>';

// iterate over your lines
$.each(data, function(i, line) {
  // check id there's sublines (may be needed to check if there's options too)
  if (line.sublines) {
    // start an opt group only if there's sublines
    dropdown += '<optgroup label="' + line + '">';

    // iterate over it's options
    $.each(line.sublines.options, function(j, option) {
      // add the option to the html
      dropdown += '<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>';
    });

    // close the opt group
    dropdown += '</optgroup>';
  }
});

// replace the select content and trigger a change
$('[name="line"]').html(dropdown).select2('enable', true).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Looks good but it's not getting past this `if (line.sublines) {`

Comment: Ok, and what's the error you're getting? Would you put an `console.log(line);` just before it and send the output?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `subLine` exists previously:

```
if (this.sublines.options) {
            $(this.sublines.options).each(function() {
                if (this.subLine)
                    dropdown += '<option value="' + this.subLine + '">' + this.subLine + '</option>';
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly in your JSON response not all objects from the array have the property `sublines`. And this is the line which is make the code to fail.

```
if (this.sublines.options) {
```

I'd suggest improving it to the following by checking if it has the property or not:

```
if (this.sublines && this.sublines.options) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for sublines *first*...

```
  if (this.sublines) {
    if (this.sublines.options) {
        $(this.sublines.options).each(function() {
            dropdown += '<option value="' + this.subLine + '">' + this.subLine + '</option>';
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve something like this:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a3bx77vm/3/

```js
var dropdown = '';
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++)
{
    dropdown += '<option></option>';
    var eachdata = data[i];
    
    dropdown += '<optgroup label="' + eachdata.line + '">';
    
    if(eachdata.sublines)
    {
        if (eachdata.sublines.options) {
            $(eachdata.sublines.options).each(function() {
                dropdown += '<option value="' + this.subLine + '">' + this.subLine + '</option>';
            });
        }
    }
    
    dropdown += '</optgroup>';
}
$("#dropdown").append($(dropdown));
```

The parsing was wrong because the data you get is an array, and it doesn't have property called lines.